# parquet format HDFS write

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, parquet

I am trying to convert a kafka message which is a huge RDD to parquet format and save in HDFS using spark streaming. Its a syslog message, like name1=value1|name2=value2|name3=value3 in each line, any pointers on how to achieve this in spark streaming ?

Answer (score 2):

You can save an `RDD` to parquet without converting to `DataFrame` as long as you have an `avro` schema for it

here is a sample function:

```
public <T> void save(JavaRDD<T> rdd, Class<T> clazz, Time timeStamp, Schema schema, String path) throws IOException {
    Job job = Job.getInstance();
    ParquetOutputFormat.setWriteSupportClass(job, AvroWriteSupport.class);
    AvroParquetOutputFormat.setSchema(job, schema);
    LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass(job, new ParquetOutputFormat<T>().getClass());
    job.getConfiguration().set("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs", "false"); 
    job.getConfiguration().set("parquet.enable.summary-metadata", "false"); 

    //save the file
    rdd.mapToPair(me -> new Tuple2(null, me))
            .saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
                    String.format("%s/%s", path, timeStamp.milliseconds()),
                    Void.class,
                    clazz,
                    LazyOutputFormat.class,
                    job.getConfiguration());
}
```

Comment: Thanks David and Sebastian , I have tried David's method , and was successful, I would like to try avro stuff, but looks like both methods do the same internally , read and convert the whole rdd to parquet using  rows or avro objects to parquet, you guys see any advantages over the other ?

Comment: But has some overhead to create the dataframe (convert types etc etc) which you can overcome by saving directly with something like the above. If performance is not an issue (say not saving frequently / big windows) then the oneliner is fine

Answer (score 1):

First [convert the `RDD` to a `DataFrame`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#interoperating-with-rdds). Then [save](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#saving-to-persistent-tables).